# Image3D: Specify distance between image slices

Tags: image-processing, image3d, rendering

When applying Image3D to an array of binary images, how can I specify the Z-depth between these images? Consider the RegionPlot3D of $x y z < 1$:

```
IR = ImplicitRegion[x y z < 1, {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[IR, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Now, I create an image stack by applying RegionPlot (the 2D version) with varying Z coordinate.

```
Slices[zval_] := RegionPlot[{
   x y zval < 1
   }, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  Frame -> None, Background -> Black, PlotStyle -> White, 
  BoundaryStyle -> White]
binaryImageStack = Binarize /@ Slices /@ Range[-4, 4, 0.5]
```

[image]

Then I apply Image3D to the image stack.

```
Image3D[binaryImageStack]
```

[image]

How can I specify the spacing between slices to Image3D? I realise that you can use BoxRatios to adapt the Z scaling, but that is only a Graphics3D option. Surely 3D morphological image processing commands like Erosion, Dilation, MorphologicalComponents etc. must be affected by the wrong specification of Z spacing?

Comment: If it's for visualization purpose only, take a look at [BoxRatios](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxRatios.html). [ImageResize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html) could be helpful too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Image3D[binaryImageStack]`, you're essentially defining your image using a 3D array of pixels (360x360x17 in your case). And you can't specify non-cubic pixels (it doesn't make much sense, just think about a 2D image).

#### Update 2

This is a bit of a refinement of the idea presented below. The idea is to pad the image using fixed padding before doing anything to remove border defects:

```
Image3D[
 Binarize@*
   Show@*
   (ImageMesh[#, BaseStyle -> White, Background -> Black, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> -50] &)@*
   (ImagePad[#, 50, "Fixed"] &) /@
  Image3DSlices[Image3D@binaryImageStack, All, 2]
 ]
```

Other than that, it works similarly to the earlier version, but is a bit cleaner.

#### Update

As noted by @szabolcs in the comments, you can simply resize the image using [`ImageResize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageResize.html), which produces something very similar to my original approach. The issue is still the same, i.e. you get more or less sharp steps.

The following demonstrates an idea how to fix this issue: (this is just an initial attempt, so don't expect perfect results)

```
Image3D[
 ColorNegate@Binarize@Show[#, AspectRatio -> 1] &@*
   DiscretizeRegion /@
  DeleteCases[EmptyRegion[2]][
   ImageMesh /@
    Image3DSlices[Image3D@binaryImageStack, All, 2]
   ]
 ]
```

The idea is to use the ability of [`ImageMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html) to connect corners diagonally, providing us a nice interpolation. Since this only works on 2D images, we create slices from our 3D images (along the x or y axis, so that the z axis is in plane). After dropping empty slices (ideally you'd replace them with an empty image), we call [`DiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeRegion.html) (this seems to improve the results a bit) and convert the slices back to images (this time with a square aspect ratio). As noted before, the result is far from perfect, but might give you a starting point if you need nicer images and can't get more slices.

#### Rest of original post

What you can do: Calculate your missing images using [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) (assuming calculating them takes too long, otherwise just calculate enough):

```
binaryImageStack = Binarize@*Slices /@ Range[-4, 4, 0.5]
interpol = Interpolation[binaryImageStack, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
Image3D@Array[interpol, 360, {1, 17}]
```

(The numbers in the last line are the image dimension (360) and the number of images in the interpolation (17) - alternatively, you could just specify the z-values in `Interpolation`)

This yields:

[image]

Note that 0th order interpolation gives you sharp steps in the resulting image, which isn't so nice - you might have to play a bit with it. One thing I tried was to not `Binarize` the images before the interpolation, but afterwards. (the result looked a bit strange though)

Comment: "you can't specify non-cubic pixels (it doesn't make much sense" With 3D images it's common—I would say typical—to use non-cubic pixels because often the data is scanned slice by slice (thus the inter-slice distance is independent of the xy plane pixel size). Take a look at the BoxRatios option example of Image3D in the docs.

Comment: @Szabolcs As already noted by OP, this seems to only affect display, without changing the actual dimensions of the image, possibly causing unexpected results when using pixel based functions.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read carefully. The question is not very well phrased though, as he was asking about the inter-slice distance multiple times. It does look like he wants to upsample. Isn't `ImageResize` better for that?  It also does interpolation (multiple methods available).

Comment: It seems to always use nearest neighbour for 3D images, regardless of the `Resampling` option ...

Comment: I played a bit more with this today, and it does appear that `ImageResize` can correctly use all resampling methods in 3D (contrary to what I said yesterday).  It's also worth noting that the image is binary (`"Bit"` type) so there won't be any other values than 0 and 1. But the resampling is still done with real values, then the result is binarized again.  Apart from `ImageResize`, there is also `ArrayResample`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I played a bit more with my idea, but the result is still not fully satisfactory. The main issue with most methods, including `ImageResize` and `ArrayResample`, seems to be that we don't want to interpolate values at each point, but somehow the structure of the images.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I made good progress analysing a microscopy image stack with your interpolation method (first version). I appreciate the improved versions too. If Wolfram is reading this, it would still be really helpful to have (say) an optional parameter in Image3D to specify a list of Z coordinates for the images in the stack.